# Check if array exists in json Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a json file from the twitter api. 
Sometimes it does have the media[0] array and sometimes it doesnt.
If it does i want to add the array to another array so it reminds it otherwise i want it to check the next one.

this is what i tried but it didnt work fine yet.

```
if(twitter.statuses[key].entities.media[0].media_url!=="Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"){
    console.log(twitter.statuses[key].entities.media[0].media_url);
}
```

It keeps giving the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
if the media array doesnt exist otherwise it works fine and goes further.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because you want to retrieve first element of ... nothing (twitter.statuses[key].entities.media[0]; media is already a null and you can't access first element of null)

Try checking with

```
if (typeof twitter.statuses[key].entities.media != "undefined") {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks this worked i kept trying this with media[0] instead of media thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

An undefined property has the [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) type and value, you can check against it like this:

```
if (twitter.statuses[key].entities.media !== undefined) {
    // ...
}
```

or like this:

```
if (typeof twitter.statuses[key].entities.media !== "undefined") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: this doesnt work media[0] gives the same error as above but without the [0] it works fine thanks!

Comment: I shouldn't post answers before coffee… fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to always initialize variables to check null or undefined values.
In your case:

```
var media0 = twitter.statuses[key].entities.media[0] || null;
if(media0 != null){
    if(media0.media_url != null)
       console.log(twitter.statuses[key].entities.media[0].media_url);
    else
       console.log('twitter.statuses[key].entities.media[0].media_url is null or not defined');
}
else
    console.log('twitter.statuses[key].entities.media[0] is null or not defined');
```